# How to use Audio files in React?

Tags: reactjs

In my code with every click on "play" the url of an id (lets say id = 1) gets extracted from the "myData" Array, this id's url is being copied to another state/property called cloneUrl, also with the click the playAudio function runs (which actually copy the url at first place) to play the audio. But, even after getting the url, render function is not playing the audio. Why ?

Link to my sandbox here, https://codesandbox.io/s/sound-app-to-be-continuee-wm3xq

or you can see the code below,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cloneUrl: "",
    myData: [
      {
        id: 1,
        letter: "Q",
        url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        letter: "W",
        url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_2.mp3"
      },
      { id: 3, letter: "E", url: "none" },
      { id: 4, letter: "A", url: "none" },
      { id: 5, letter: "S", url: "none" },
      { id: 6, letter: "D", url: "none" },
      { id: 7, letter: "Z", url: "none" },
      { id: 8, letter: "X", url: "none" },
      { id: 9, letter: "C", url: "none" }
    ]
  };

  playAudio = (data) => {
    this.setState({ cloneUrl: data });
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
    audioEl.play();
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.cloneUrl);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.myData.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.letter}
            <audio className="audio-element">
              <source src={this.state.cloneUrl}></source>
            </audio>
            <button onClick={() => this.playAudio(item.url)}>play</button>
            <hr />
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already passed the url through playAudio. You can play it this way.

```
  playAudio = (data) => {
   
    let audio = new Audio(data)
    audio.play();
  };
```